# Need a way to add the results obtained from the MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables

- `Employee(eid, ename, deptid)`
- `ESal(eid, salary)`
- `EDept(deptid, dept)`

Is there a way to get the total salary paid by department and also get the total salary paid in the same query.

Something like this:

```
   Dept1  |  100 
   Dept2  |  300
   Dept3  |  200
   Total  |  600
```

Comment: Yes of course. What have you tried?

Comment: What is field that contains `Dept1`, `Dept2`, `Dept3` values?

Comment: Does `EDept.deputed` = `Employee.deptid` ?

Comment: You could try joining Esal and Employee on Edept grouping by the Edept primary key. Then you could select the Edept deputed column and count(Esal.salary).

Comment: `WITH ROLLUP` is what I was looking for.  So basically I resolved the same by doing the following,

Comment: @SudeepPadalkar you can obtain salary department wise and after that make sum for total,,, is this right way ?

Comment: edept,depted my head hurts :-(

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to resolve the same

I essentially performed a `left join` of `employee` table with the `edept` and the `esal` table and performed a group by on salary. To get the total performed a `WITH ROLLUP` which gave me the total of all the retrieved salaries

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+-----+-------+--------+
| eid | ename | deptid |
+-----+-------+--------+
|   1 | emp1  |      1 |
|   2 | emp2  |      1 |
|   3 | emp3  |      2 |
|   4 | emp4  |      3 |
|   5 | emp5  |      3 |
|   6 | emp6  |      2 |
+-----+-------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from edept;
+--------+-------+
| deptid | dept  |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | HR    |
|      2 | Admin |
|      3 | Dev   |
+--------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from esal;
+-----+--------+
| eid | salary |
+-----+--------+
|   1 |    100 |
|   2 |    200 |
|   3 |    230 |
|   4 |    120 |
|   5 |    400 |
|   6 |    100 |
+-----+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


   SELECT ifnull(dept, 'Total') as 'Dept', sum( salary ) 
       AS 'salary' FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN edept  ON employee.deptid = edept.deptid 
LEFT JOIN esal  ON employee.eid = esal.eid 
 GROUP BY dept 
     with rollup;

+-------+--------+
| Dept  | salary |
+-------+--------+
| Admin |    330 |
| Dev   |    520 |
| HR    |    300 |
| Total |   1150 |
+-------+--------+
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). Something like this maybe :

```
(
SELECT
    EDept.dept,
    e.salary
FROM
    EDept 
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            e.deptid,
            SUM(s.salary) as salary
        FROM
            Employee as e
            JOIN ESal as s
                ON e.eid = s.eid
        GROUP BY 
            e.deptid
    ) as e
        ON e.deptid = EDept.deptid
)
UNION
(
SELECT
    "Total",
    SUM(salary)
FROM
    ESal
)
```